# Yii 2 форма из нескольких моделей

Tags: php, yii2

делаю по примеру https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28567736/yii2-multiple-forms-in-a-single-action

две модели - human и passport

контролер

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $human = new Human();
    $passport = new Passport;

    if ($human->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $passport->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && Model::validateMultiple([$human, $passport]))
    {

        $human->save(false); // skip validation as model is already validated
        $passport->id = $human->passport_id; // no need for validation rule on user_id as you set it yourself
        $passport->save(false);

        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $human->id]);
    }
    else
    {
        return $this->render('create', [
                    'human' => $human,
                    'passport' => $passport,
        ]);
    }

    /* if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    } else {
        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }*/
}
```

view

```
    <?php

    use yii\helpers\Html;
    use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
    use app\modules\proj\models\Passport;

    /* @var $this yii\web\View */
    /* @var $model app\modules\proj\models\Human */
    /* @var $form yii\widgets\ActiveForm */
    ?>

    <div class="human-form">

        <?php
        $form = ActiveForm::begin([
                    'id' => $human->isNewRecord ? 'human-form-create' : 'human-form-update',
        ]);
        ?>

        <?= $form->field($human, 'name')->textarea(['rows' => 6]) ?>

            <?= $form->field($human, 'passport_id')->textInput() ?>

        <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton($human->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update', ['class' => $human->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
        </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

    </div>
```

получаю

> Call to a member function formName() on a non-object

Comment: С виду должно работать, или может пример не полный (особенно в плане вьюхи). Зачем вам лоад параметров и валидация для passport, если во вьюхе заполняется только human?

Comment: да вообще он модели не видит http://i.imgur.com/GEQ1csK.png

Comment: в контроллере уж тогда смотреть, что там за объекты создаются

Comment: там нормально модели отображаются

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/SVqgAm0.png

Comment: пишите лучше return $this->render('create', compact('human', 'passport')); если так и не поборете - запостите последнюю версию контроллера и вью, ничего не вырезая и не меняя...

Comment: полное решение http://des1roer.blogspot.ru/2016/01/yii-2_18.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

проблема в том что нужно еще и в файле  views/create.php передать параметры

```
<?= $this->render('_form', [
    'model' => $model,
    'model_' => $model_
]) ?>
```

Comment: я вам так и написал в первом же комментарии, что пример скорее всего не полный в плане вьюхи) там никакого второго рендера не было

Comment: @kroder а так всегда, люди сокращают код, в надежде, что телепатия всё же победит